# LinuxからSMSへメッセージ送信したい

Tags: linux, monitoring, mobile

携帯電話のSMSへメッセージを送信するにはどうしたら良いでしょうか。
Cronの実行結果やエラーを携帯に送信したいと思っています。

通信事業者はドコモです。
費用が発生するものでも大丈夫です。
MMSについてはドコモが採用していないようなので今回は除外します。

Comment: Internet側から、SMSへ送るためのプロトコルなどは、標準化されていますが、その機能を、開放しているか、いくらの費用がかかるのかは、通信事業者によって異なります。従って、どの事業者、あるいは事業者を縛らない、有料でよいのか、無料でないとダメなのか、を明記したほうが、良いと思います。また、MMSでは、だめなのかも。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。質問内容に追記しました。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

APIでSMSを送るサービスがいくつかあります。

有名どこだとTwilioさんとかでしょうか
http://twilio.kddi-web.com/function/sms/

Comment: RESTで呼び出すんですね。RESTはチンプンカンプンなのですが、コマンドラインから実行できるか教えて頂けると助かります。

Comment: 自己解決しました。curl でRESTを呼び出せることを知りました。ありがとうございます。